# Can't load images in browser cache with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a small jQuery program which implements an image slideshow with a fading effect. When an image is rendered and the next one has to be shown, it is first loaded in background and then rendered. The code loading the image is below:

```
    var img = $('<img/>'); 
    img.attr('src', imageUrl);

    img.load(function()
      {
        $(photo).attr('loaded' + mediaSize, true)
                .attr('width',              this.width)
                .attr('height',             this.height);
        renderPhoto(photo, mediaSize);
      });
```

The relevant part for rendering the photo in renderPhoto() is:

```
    $("#image" + activeContainer).css({ "background-image" : "url(" + imageUrl + ")" });
```

There's also a control that keeps track of loaded images and doesn't re-read them twice, supposing that, having been loaded earlier, they are in the browser cache.

Everything is working fine but the cache. Whenever an image is rendered (with the latest line of code above), it is always reloaded from the server, ruining the fade-in effect.

The headers returned by the server seems ok for caching:

```
% curl -o /tmp/x -v http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20100102-0072/1280/image.jpg
* About to connect() to stoppingdown.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 78.46.194.117...   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0connected
* Connected to stoppingdown.net (78.46.194.117) port 80 (#0)
> GET /media/stillimages/20100102-0072/1280/image.jpg HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: stoppingdown.net
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 04 Nov 2012 11:52:08 GMT
< X-NorthernWind-Version: 1.1-ALPHA-19
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Content-Length: 2207579
< Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Nov 2012 00:08:11 CET
< ETag: "1351724891000"
< Expires: Sun, 11 Nov 2012 12:52:08 CET
< Server: Jetty(6.1.24)
< 
{ [data not shown]
```

Debugging with Chrome and looking at the resources pane, I can see multiple entries for the same image, reloaded at each round (for instance, at first round I see 20031227-0085.jpg, and when the slideshow starts a second cycle I see two 20031227-0085.jpg, then three, and so on). Definitely the resource is not loaded in the browser cache... and I don't understand why.

Thanks.

PS The full code is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/tidalwave/bluette-src/src/810394e72951dea6eaacc8019a995c87273487c0/bluette/js/bluette.js?at=default).

Comment: load not fired when image in cache, check .complete property if image

Comment: you can also add something like `'?rand='.Math.random()`  to `imageUrl`

Comment: ah lol, reread question, you preloading image incorrect, lol

Comment: read the docs `Caveats of the load event when used with images` section. http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ Try searching this site, there are 100's of similar posts

Comment: @eicto I've read about the .complete property - I expect this to be my next problem, as soon as I manage to have the cache working :-)

Comment: i don't think you load image , if you want to load it hidden from user, just load it to hidden div

Comment: @charlietfl Please re-read my question: all the other posts that I've found are about people wanting to bypass cache. In my case, I want cache but it's not working.

Comment: @eicto What are you meaning by "I don't think you load image"? BTW, the image is actually set as the background of a hidden div.

Comment: you need an image preload method that works with cache..understood... again, this is a very common topic on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I've found that my jQuery code was properly working, indeed. The problem was with the server, which didn't properly support caching (it was always sending back a 200 HTTP status with a payload even when a 304 "Not Modified" was supposed to be used). Fixing the problem in the server fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

see the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/p3hsf/) with jquery, how you can preload image, without show it while you load:

HTML:

```
​<div>Here will be image</div>
<button>Click to load</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
.images {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black; 
 transition: background 1s,width 1s,height 1s;
 -webkit-transition: background 1s,width 1s,height 1s;
 -mozilla-transition: background 1s,width 1s,height 1s;
 -o-transition: background 1s,width 1s,height 1s;
}​
```

JS:

```
var showimage = function(image) {
    var div = $('.images');
    div.empty();
    div.width(image.get(0).width);
    div.height(image.get(0).height);
    div.css({
        'background-image': "url(" + image.attr('src') + ")"
    });

}

var images = ['http://www.dragongoserver.net/images/dragonlogo_bl.jpg', 'http://www.dragongoserver.net/images/dragon_logo.jpg', 'http://cdn.last.fm/flatness/listen/radio_icon_medium.png']
$('button').click(function() {
    var image = $(new Image());
    image.attr('src', images[0]);
    images.push(images.shift());
    if (image.get(0).complete === true) {
        showimage(image);
    } else {
        image.load(function() {
            console.log('loading...');
            showimage(image);
        });
    }
});​
```

Comment: Interesting, because I didn't know transition - also because it's CSS3 and I was keeping compatibility with plain CSS. But I bet in 2012 I can upgrade. It would simplify my code. I'll try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: you can easy translate that to jquery animation